# Ошибка в Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? При создании нового пустого проекта, написав в нем простейшую программу Hello World (правильно), Visual C++ при компиляции выдает ошибку, см. скриншот.

[image]

P.S. Проверял, есть ли в папке Debug файл exe, то там его действительно нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш проект не скомпилировался, посмотрите на вывод в консоли. Скорее всего, при создании проекта вы включили использование предкомпилированного заголовочного файла (`stdafx.h`), а затем удалили его. Или включили эту опцию в настройках проекта после создания. Вам нужно либо отключить использование предкомпилированного заголовочного файла (**Свойства проекта** -> **C/C++** -> **Предкомпилированные заголовки** -> **Создать или использовать предкомпилированный заголовок** -> **Не использовать предкомпилированный заголовок**), либо создать заголовочный файл `stdafx.h` и включать его в каждый `.cpp` файл вашего проекта.